# WinXP BSOD when run on Qemu

Tags: windows-xp, virtualization, bsod, qemu

I have an old virtual machine on virtual box with WinXP, I converted it on raw QEMU format, I tried to run this image on Win10 and on Debian but I have this BSOD.

This is the command line on Windows I try to run it

```
"C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe" -drive format=raw,file=winxp.img -L "C:\Program Files\qemu"
```

My version of QEMU on Windows 10

> QEMU emulator version 5.2.0 (v5.2.0-11852-g66075e5998-dirty)

This is the error message

> *** STOP: 0x0000007B (0xF7A09528,0xC0000034,0x00000000,0x00000000)

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: 07b is inaccessible boot device.  Likely since you've completely changed the hardware XP is expecting to see and run on.  Option 1, run it on VirtualBox.  Option 2, boot the VM from an XP ISO and do a repair install, the 2nd repair option, not the first.

Comment: Thank you, I recovered the boot  from WinXP CD-ROM

Answer (score 0):

As comment says, 0x0000007b means a missing boot device. That makes very likely, that the default install of your winxp has no driver for the virtual hard disk interface, what the qemu provides for him.

Play with the `-device` flags, and google on the net, odds are very high that qemu can provide a virtual hard disk controller which has a driver in the default winxp install.

Note, the beginning of the installation worked only because it has happened yet with virtual bios (provided also by the qemu). As you see the blue death, you are already in protected mode, without access to the bios drivers. WinXP needs to load the hard disk controller driver at that time, it did not happen.

This command works by me:

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda work/winxp.img \
  -cdrom dl/winxp.iso -boot d -cpu qemu64 -m 512 \
  -vga cirrus -display vnc=0.0.0.0:1 \
  -net nic,model=rtl8139 -net user
```

and it results a working winxp. How can I make it better (like using virtio and so), not even I have a clue yet.